# MOT coverage for car issues

Tags: service, motors, tires

This is a very UK specific question. I was wondering what sort of tests and (if any) fixes are covered by MOT tests. I know that lots of auto shops do servicing that focus on the MOT aspects of things (e.g. the Halfords multipoint check).

An example is that I had a interim/full service last year and have done about 800 miles since then. My front left tyre appears to be slightly deflated, but a repair shop told me that they pressure gauged OK (wth). Now, my MOT is due very soon (in 2 months). Will they do some minor repairs such as reinflating tyres if the pressure is not right? Or they just report it to me and say that it will need to be repaired?

Answer (score 5):

The MOT only checks a specific set of things, as described in the link in Chenmunka's answer. Tyre pressure isn't one of them, but tyre condition and tread depth are. Some MOT stations (usually the smaller ones) will fix minor things as they go, big ones won't as they can charge you extra to do things afterwards!

However - it is your responsibility (by law) to keep your car roadworthy - if your tyres are under-inflated, you need to inflate them now, not wait until the next MOT. If nothing else, it will save you money, as an under-inflated tyre will wear out quicker than a correctly inflated one, and cause worse fuel economy...

Answer (score 4):

This is all explained on the Government website for the [MOT](https://www.gov.uk/getting-an-mot/the-mot-test).
The leaflets are kept up to date at legislation changes.

Whether an individual test centre will fix minor faults like tyre pressure is down to the centre.

Answer (score 2):

An MOT in the UK will test [these things](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/449392/mot-inspection-checklist-vt29.pdf). For more details on how they test your car, [see here](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/car-parts-checked-at-an-mot/car-parts-checked-at-an-mot). Your car will either get a pass or a fail for each one. If get a fail in any one of the categories, that will constitute a fail overall.

They are ***not*** required to do any work on the car, not even adjust the tire pressure or replace a bulb. Some might be kind to you and do it (to keep you as a customer) and others may not, but that is up to the discretion of each MOT and service place independently.

That is most places, including Halfords I believe, will sell an MOT Service. This allows you to renew your MOT (i.e. no fail in most cases), as well as service your car without duplicating many of the tasks that they would have to do twice if you paid for a service and then an MOT separately. This allows them to be able to pass the savings on to you - the customer.